# decipher encoding UTF-8 Issue

Tags: encoding, utf-8

I have to compare 2 text files generated from SQL server(generated directly) and Impala ( through Unix).Both are saved as UTF-8 file. I have converted the SQL server generated file using dos2unix for direct compare in unix. I have some data which is encoded and am not able to check what the encoding is. 
Below is some sample data from SQL server file.
`Rock<81>ller`
`<81>hern`
`<81>ber`
`R<81>cking`

Below is sample data from Unix file.

`Rock�ller`
`�ber`
                                                                                                                                                  `R�cking`

`�ber`

I checked the file using HXD editor and both SQL server generated data and unix file showed code 81. I looked up code 81 in UTF and found it is control<> character. 
I am really lost as encoding is fairly new to me. Any help to decipher what encoding it is actualy used would be very helpful.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know how to set the correct encoding here and view correct values. Both files are utf 8 . I see these values, I am not sure if these are junk values being inserted.

Comment: It's not clear what you actually have in those files. Can you post a hex dump?